# Swift | UIViewTable changes checkmark when scrolled off screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a list of TableViewCells (todoList.items) inside a TableView. I can toggle the checkmarks easily and that works. But, when the cells are scrolled off the edge of the table view, the checkmark toggles itself unexpectedly.

In my view controller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChecklistItem", for: indexPath)
    let item = todoList.items[indexPath.row]
    configureText(for: cell, with: item)
    configureCheckmark(for: cell, with: item)

    return cell
}

// **EDIT**
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        let item = todoList.items[indexPath.row]
        configureCheckmark(for: cell, with: item)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

func configureCheckmark(for cell: UITableViewCell, with item: ChecklistItem) {
    cell.accessoryType = item.checked ? .checkmark : .none
    item.toggleChecked()
}

// **END EDIT**
```

TodoList.swift

```
class TodoList {

    var items: [ChecklistItem] = []

    init() {
        // Create some demo items
        items.append(ChecklistItem(text: "Take a jog"))
        items.append(ChecklistItem(text: "Watch a movie"))
        items.append(ChecklistItem(text: "Code an app"))
        items.append(ChecklistItem(text: "Walk the dog"))
        items.append(ChecklistItem(text: "Study design patterns"))
    }

    func newItem() -> ChecklistItem {
        items.append(ChecklistItem(text: "NEW ITEM"))
        return items[items.count-1]
    }

}
```

ChecklistItem.swift

```
class ChecklistItem {

    var text = ""
    var checked = true

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    func toggleChecked() {
        checked = !checked
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add `configureCheckmark` and `didSelectRow` methods to understand how you are handling check mark.

Comment: @MidhunMP configureCheckmark is just a wrapper to change the accessory state of the cell and to reflect that change in my checklist model (ChecklistItem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you toggle the `checked` state **always** in `configureCheckmark`. So whenever `cellForRow` is called for this row the state is toggled.

Actually an extra method `configureCheckmark` is not needed. Put the line to set the checkmark in `cellForRow` but don't change the state.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChecklistItem", for: indexPath)
    let item = todoList.items[indexPath.row]
    configureText(for: cell, with: item)
    cell.accessoryType = item.checked ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectRowAt` toggle `checked` in the model and reload the row

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    todoList.items[indexPath.row].checked.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

The method `toggleChecked()` in `ChecklistItem` is redundant, too. There is a `toggle()` method in `Bool`.

And consider to use structs rather than classes.

Comment: I do update the model as well... I have a method to do this for me, it is called configureCheckmark